# how do i map a a vector of numbers to colors in python?

Tags: python, django, matplotlib

I'm having trouble finding a way to convert a vector of numbers to a "good" color scale (ala matplotlib) so that I can simply have just the vector of the color values.  This is useful for rendering some static html pages in django.  Any thoughts?

Thanks for the answers folks! Really helpful!

Comment: The mapping isn't necessarily unique.  You can make up any mapping you like.

Answer (score 1):

You may use the following code:

```
from __future__ import division

import numpy
import matplotlib.cm as cmap

r = numpy.random.rand(1000)                             #random numbers
c = cmap.jet(numpy.int_((r-r.min())/r.ptp()*255))       #colors
```

so you try:

```
>>> r
array([ 0.88741281,  0.61022571,  0.14819983,  0.3695846 ,  0.73832029,
        0.6266069 ,  0.6917337 ,  0.09162752,  0.83532511,  0.54001574, ...,])
>>> c
array([[ 1.        ,  0.08787219,  0.        ,  1.        ],
       [ 0.83175206,  1.        ,  0.13598988,  1.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.08039216,  1.        ,  1.        ],
       ..., 
       [ 0.        ,  0.72352941,  1.        ,  1.        ],
       [ 0.24984187,  1.        ,  0.71790006,  1.        ],
       [ 1.        ,  0.45098039,  0.        ,  1.        ]])
```

which are colors each row in the format of RGBA.

Answer (score 0):

you can also give a look at [ColorConverter](http://matplotlib.org/api/colors_api.html#matplotlib.colors.ColorConverter). It provides a few methods to convert valid matplotlib colors to RGB or RGBA.

Valid matplotlib colors are

> 1. a letter from the set ‘rgbcmykw’
> 2. a hex color string, like ‘#00FFFF’
> 3. a standard name, like ‘aqua’ a float, like ‘0.4’, indicating gray on
> 4. a 0-1 scale